# why PHP + curl, HTTP POST request returns null?

Tags: php, laravel, api, curl

i am confused why $response does not return anything ,i am new to curl please help,

```
$post = [
        'AreaCode' => '02',
        'PhoneNumber' => '33312733',
        'InquiryBy'   => 'telephone',
    ];

    $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://billing.te.eg/api/Account/Inquiry');
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
       'Content-Type:application/json',
       'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *',
     ));
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
     $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
     $response = curl_exec($ch);
     if ($response === false) $response = curl_error($ch);
     echo stripslashes($response);
     curl_close($ch);
```

while in postman

[image]

Comment: Your data does not automatically become JSON, just because you set a Content-Type header saying so. Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will result in it creating a query string-like format, name1=value1&name2=value2&... Pass a JSON string instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please add following line to define request type (GET/POST/..) and then try:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
```

Answer (score -1):

Download cacert.pem file keep in root directory and set curl option and try

http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

```
curl_setopt ($h, CURLOPT_CAINFO, base_path()."/cacert.pem");
```